# Xamarin - Back stack does not clear

Tags: c#, android, xml, android-activity, xamarin

I have a LoginActivity (this is the main activity) and after the user logs in it redirects him to another activity, howerver when he presses the back button it goes back to the login activity. I tried using 
this:

```
StartActivity(typeof(FragmentRendererActivity));
Finish();
```

and this:

```
StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(FragmentRendererActivity)));
Finish();
```

and this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(FragmentRendererActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
StartActivity(intent);
```

and this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(FragmentRendererActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
StartActivity(intent);
Finish();
```

and this:

```
<application android:label="Homecheck" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name="LoginActivity" android:noHistory="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" />
</application>
```

...but nothing worked. The closest thing I was able to get to was that I log in, I go to Activity B, I press the back button and the app exits(Paused state). I resume it and, you guessed it, I'm back at the Login Activity.
So is there a way to properly get rid of an activity in the back stack ?
P.S. Maybe the problem is that my LoginActivity is the main activity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Login is your MainActivity, everytime the app closes and opens it will be the first screen the users sees. Use a splash screen that can check if your user has already been authenticated and redirect them from there. The behaviour you talk about is the expected behaviour

Adding NoHistory = true in the attributes ontop of the class will remove it from the back stack

```
 [Activity(Label = "SampleApp", NoHistory = true)]
public class LoginActivty : Activity
{
}
```

Also another thing you can try and clear top activity

```
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SampleActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        StartActivity(intent);

        Finish();
```

Comment: @Milen if this helped you fix your problem please accept the answer

Comment: Since I am using the Trial version of Xamarin I cannot make my own Splash screen. When I get a license next month I am going to try it and if it works, I will mark it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: A Splash screen is a standard activity. it behaves like a normal screen. its just the first one that is loaded when the application loads first. you would have [Activity(Label = "Spash", MainActivity=true)]

Comment: The trial version of Xamarin has its own Splash screen that says "This build only works for 24 hours" When I tried adding my own splash it threw an error that another splash screen already exists. Can't remove it while it's in Trial.